# Python multiprocessing is not calling function

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand how multiprocessing works in Python. Here is a simple code which is not calling the function as I expected it would.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def do_something():
    print('Sleep')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Wake up')

start = time.perf_counter()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

In **Jupyter Notebook**, after executing I am getting following output:

```
Finished in 0.2 second(s)
```

I though it would be like something like this:

```
Sleep
Sleep
Wake up
Wake up
Finished in 0.2 second(s)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The output as u expected

Comment: I believe the output is in a different (sub)process?

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook it does not work as expected.

Comment: I get expected output in Jupyter Notebook on Linux Mint.

Comment: this is related to Windows ,it does not allow to spawn the process
I tried same code in Spyder and it was not working .

same code run fine in Linux or any Unix base system

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Programming guidelines" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) to figure out why you need the:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
```

guard in your scripts that use multiprocessing. Since you don't have that in your notebooks, it wont work properly.

Comment: That would make a difference on Windows (or any system opting in to the `'spawn'` start method in Python 3), but it's only a good idea, not required, on systems that use `fork`. Not clear what the OP is using, but I'd expect it to explode in other ways if this were the problem.

Comment: Tried with this. Nothing changed. Works as expected in google colab.